# Text being pushed to bottom of cell in TD

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have attached a picture of a problem I have encountered.  The text for some reason is being pushed to the bottom of the td cell in outlook 7 and 13.

```
<td width="60%" style="padding-bottom:14px;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="custom_12">
    <tr>
      <td width="100" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#005c89" style="font-size: 12px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 48px;">
        <SimpleURLProperty name="" track="true" type="plain" label="Compare Now" href="">
          <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;" class="no_ul">TEXT</a>
        </SimpleURLProperty>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: Code works fine for me...

Comment: Well for some reason in outlook the text is pushed to the bottom (screenshot is in the post - "enter image description here")

Comment: line-height: 48px; maybe ?